# Can I update existing rows in a MYSQL table with rows in a Pandas DataFrame based on an ID that exists in both?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I currently have a MYSQL table that I pull into a Pandas DF with the pd.read_sql_query function.

Example table/DF before added data:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 |  |

I then add some data to an existing column in the MYSQL table in Pandas.

Example DF after added data:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 9 |

I then want to update the rows in the MYSQL database based on the ID column.

I have tried the following:

`df.to_sql(con=conn,name='table_name',if_exists='replace',index=False)`

However, I specifically want to update the specific rows and not drop and replace the table itself.

I have tried using SQL Alchemy functions, but I don't have much experience with SQL to implement it correctly.

Comment: What happened with the command you tried?

Comment: @TimRoberts Technically it works, but I specifically want to update each row and not replace the entire table, as I will eventually use this in a loop where dropping the table every time will cause it to not function correctly.

Comment: How large is the table?  You can do `read_sql` to read the old data, then update the dataframe, then `to_sql` to write it back out.  Otherwise, you're going to end up writing SQL...

Comment: The table has 100 000+ rows and 5 columns, thus replacing the entire table with `to_sql` won't be ideal. Ideally, I'd want to use a loop to check if that specific row (with that specific ID) has a different value in the "Value" column and then update that value.

Comment: As always, if you have a need that the convenience shortcuts (like `to_sql`) don't handle, then you'll have to do it line by line.  `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` can do an insert-or-update operation in one statement.

Comment: Not sure pandas can do that. IMO an orm (such as sqlalchemy) would be more suited for the task.